# javascript array and jsf/richfaces

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, richfaces

I have the following code in javascript:

```
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/js/sample-points.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
            var cloudmade = new CM.Tiles.CloudMade.Web({key: 'bbb'});
            var map = new CM.Map('cm-example', cloudmade);
            map.setCenter(new CM.LatLng(51.50874, 22.76367), 4);

            var markers = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < samplePoints.length; i++) {
                markers.push(new CM.Marker(new CM.LatLng(samplePoints[i][0], samplePoints[i][1])));
            }

            var clusterer = new CM.MarkerClusterer(map, {clusterRadius: 70});
            clusterer.addMarkers(markers);
        //]]></script>
```

"samplePoints" is an array of coordinates which I can use to show markers on the map.

Map is showing here:

```
<div id="cm-example" style="width: 99.5%; height: 600px"></div>
```

How can I provide this array from jsf/richfaces without using file (e.g. I want to fetch those data from db, create array and send to this script)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let JSF print it as if it is JavaScript code.

Replace

```
var markers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < samplePoints.length; i++) {
    markers.push(new CM.Marker(new CM.LatLng(samplePoints[i][0], samplePoints[i][1])));
}
```

by (assuming Facelets)

```xml
var markers = [];
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.samplePoints}" var="samplePoint">
    markers.push(new CM.Marker(new CM.LatLng(#{samplePoint[0]}, #{samplePoint[1]})));
</ui:repeat>
```

where `#{bean.samplePoints}` returns a `List<BigDecimal[]>` or something.

Comment: How do you mean "by (assuming Facelets)"?

Comment: JSF can be used on old JSP or its successor Facelets (XML based). The `<ui:repeat>` is not available in old JSP. If you're using JSF 2.0 with XHTML files, then you're definitely using Facelets.

Comment: I am using JSF 1.2 with xhtml. Does that mean I cannot use <ui:repeat> ?

Comment: You can just use it. You've an `xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"` in root tag declaration, right?

Comment: Yes, I have, but when I try to execute that part of code, I think that I never reach the loop (or lines inside ui:repeat). I got this generated code:

   `<ui:repeat items="[[Ljava.lang.String;@6216cf1f]" var="samplePoint">
              markers.push(new CM.Marker(new CM.LatLng(samplePoint[0], samplePoint[1])));
    </ui:repeat>`

Bean:

`private List<String[]> samplePoints;
...
@Create
 public void init() {
  String[] a = new String[2];
  a[0] = "50.4397550076928";
  a[1] = "30.6139826774597";
  samplePoints.add(a);
 }
...
getter
setter
`

Comment: Then you don't have a `xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"` in root tag declaration.

Comment: As I said, I have. But, I found that the problem is in wrong syntax:
Instead of:
`<ui:repeat items="#{bean.samplePoints}" var="samplePoint">`
it should be:
`<ui:repeat value="#{bean.samplePoints}" var="samplePoint">`
But, thanks anyway

Comment: Oh, I confused with the `<c:forEach>` for JSP which has `items` instead of `value`. I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 1):

See this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188981/sending-ajax-request-using-javascript-to-jsf)

using jsFunction you can load any data structure (e.g. Points), and on your clients side you get a javaScript data structure that you can easily access it (point.x).