# Add onclick event on JSF custom component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I am just trying to build a custom component with :

- firstly, a basic `onclick` javascript event on my `p` tag rendered like `alert("...")`
- secondly, a server sider handling of the click event

.

```
// HelloComponent.java
@FacesComponent(createTag = true, tagName = "helloComponent", namespace = "http://example.com/tags")
public class HelloComponent extends UIComponentBase {

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return "Greeting";
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
        String message = (String) getAttributes().get("message");

        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        writer.startElement("p", this);
        writer.write(message);
        writer.endElement("p");
    }
}


// index.xhtml (simplified)
<html ...>
    <h:body>
        <t:helloComponent message="Hello World !" />
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I've been reading things about events/behaviors but I can not figure it out how it works.

Comment: Just use `writer.writeAttribute(...)`? Or are you actually trying to ask how to listen for it in server side? (because that's where events/behaviors actually come into the play).

Comment: @BalusC yes that's it, I want server side handling.

Comment: Then I don't understand the phrase "a basic onclick event" and the `alert(...)` example at all. This contradicts with the apparent wish to invoke a JSF bean action method.

Comment: @BalusC the first step of building user interaction was to have client side handling but I was going to ask for server side rendering right after. I just edited my post.

Comment: So you want to let JSF generate a script which sends an ajax request to the server side? This is absolutely not "a basic onclick event like alert()". In the end you seem to merely want your component to support `<f:ajax>`. Lookup the `ClientBehaviorHolder` interface if that indeed suits your wish.

Comment: @BalusC I just want to set up an onclick event on my `p` that trigger a backing method on my component.

Comment: So in the end you want to be able to use something like `<t:helloComponent ajaxListener="#{bean.method}"/>` instead of `<t:helloComponent><f:ajax listener="#{bean.method}"/></t:helloComponent>`?

Comment: Both are good, in fact, I'm creating a JSF component to embed a JS library, so I need to call in my javascript (which will be embed in my component) the ajax listener method of the component.

Comment: Because I want to be able to pass the data of my javascript library to my backing bean at any moment from my javascript calling the ajax listener of the component.

Comment: So in the end you want to duplicate the functionality of existing `<h:commandScript>` / `<p:remoteCommand>` / `<o:commandScript>` components? Might be worth the effort to just look in their source code how they did it. Or simply use them. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16588327 and  https://stackoverflow.com/q/15550165

Comment: Those comments does not allow to pass data through it, is there any way ? As I'm using a javascript library, the data are in javascript and I need to handle them in my backing bean. It would be like an `onchange` event in javascript that send new data to backing bean.

Comment: Comments? You mean components? Surely they allow parameter passing. See their documentation.

Comment: Yes, components, sorry. I am using `<h:commandScript>` now, but it uses `toString` to pass to java, so from an javascript array of objects `[{x: 2}, {x: 4}]`, I receive `[object Object],[object Object]` in my bean, any help on this ?

Comment: Not sure where you this was shown in h:commandScript documentation, but that's recognizable as parameter syntax for p:remoteCommand. Are you sure you're not mixing up things?

Comment: I have `<h:commandScript name="commandScript" action="#{helloBean.process}" />` and I call it in javascript through `commandScript({ arr: [{x: 12}, {x: 4} ] })`, and in my `process` method : `System.out.println(Faces.getRequestParameter("positions"));` prints `[object Object],[object Object]`.

Comment: HTTP request parameters are strings. In client side, you need to convert objects to strings first. In server side, you need to convert strings to objects. This is not a JSF problem.

Comment: Oh alright, as it just ajax behind all this I'm gonna use json format to pass data to my bean method. Thanks for this @BalusC !

Comment: @BalusC just another quick question, I finally ended by create a component extending OmniFaces `CommandScript`, and as I said before, I pass my data from javascript to my backing bean method through a JSON string, is there any way to create a java data structure with this string before sending data to backing bean ? Like a `beforeAction` that could process the javascript string received and return a Java object.

Comment: As you're using OmniFaces already, just use `@Param` with `converter` attribute to inject and convert a HTTP request parameter using JSF-managed converters.

Comment: But where should I put it ? On my backing bean method ? The point of what I was talking about is to handle everything in my component **before** the backing bean receive the data (so that is much cleaner as backing bean will receive clean java objects instead of JSON string)