# How to invoke a JSF managed bean on a HTML DOM event using native JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces, facelets

I need to execute a JSF managed bean action method using ajax during HTML DOM `load` event, similar to jQuery's `$(document).ready(function() { $.ajax(...) })`. I can only use the JavaScript generated by JSF in this project. Is there a way to do it in native JSF? Which event can I use or which JSF ajax function can I use?

I'm using JSF 2.0, Facelets and PrimeFaces.

Comment: @Heppy: No, it definitely doesn't. Are you new to JSF?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Several ways.

1. Use `<h:commandScript>`. Note that this is only available since JSF 2.3.

   ```html
    <h:form>
        <h:commandScript name="commandName" action="#{bean.action}" render=":results" />
    </h:form>
    <h:panelGroup id="results">
        ...
    </h:panelGroup>
   ```

   You can invoke it in JS as below:

   ```
    commandName();
   ```

   The parameters can be passed as below:

   ```
    commandName({ name1: "value1", name2: "value2" });
   ```

   And obtained as below:

   ```
    String name1 = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().get("name1"); // value1
    String name2 = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().get("name2"); // value2
   ```

   To invoke it during `load` event, set `autorun="true"`.

   ```
    <h:commandScript ... autorun="true" />
   ```

   ---
2. If you're using PrimeFaces, use its [`<p:remoteCommand>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml).

   ```html
    <h:form>
        <p:remoteCommand name="commandName" action="#{bean.action}" update=":results" />
    </h:form>
    <h:panelGroup id="results">
        ...
    </h:panelGroup>
   ```

   You can invoke it in JS as below:

   ```
    commandName();
   ```

   This however doesn't use JSF native [`jsf.ajax.request()`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/jsdocs/symbols/jsf.ajax.html#constructor), instead it uses PrimeFaces native jQuery (you know, PrimeFaces is a JSF component library on top of jQuery/UI).

   The parameters can be passed as below:

   ```
    commandName([{ name: "name1", value: "value1" }, { name: "name2", value: "value2" }]);
   ```

   And obtained as below:

   ```
    String name1 = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().get("name1"); // value1
    String name2 = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().get("name2"); // value2
   ```

   To invoke it during `load` event, set `autoRun="true"`.

   ```
    <p:remoteCommand ... autoRun="true" />
   ```

   ---
3. If you're using OmniFaces, use its [`<o:commandScript>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/commandScript). The usage is exactly the same as with `<h:commandScript>` but then available for older JSF 2.x versions.

   Simply replace `h:` by `o:` in the first example. Historical note: the `<h:commandScript>` is entirely based off `<o:commandScript>`.

   ---
4. Use the "hidden form" trick (actually, "hack" is given the ugliness a better wording).

   ```html
    <h:form id="form" style="display:none;">
        <h:commandButton id="button" action="#{bean.action}">
            <f:ajax render=":results" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
    <h:panelGroup id="results">
        ...
    </h:panelGroup>
   ```

   You can invoke it in JS as below:

   ```
    document.getElementById("form:button").onclick();
   ```

   Note the importance of triggering `onclick()` instead of `click()`. The `onclick()` immediately invokes the generated `onclick` function, while the `click()` basically only simulates the "click" action on the element, as if a mouse is used, which is not supported in IE, and in some browsers also require the element being actually interactable (i.e. `display:none` can't be used then).

   You can pass parameters via `<h:inputHidden>` in same form which you fill by JS beforehand. This is demonstrated in [How to pass JavaScript variables as parameters to JSF action method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591301/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-as-parameters-to-jsf-action-method/28601362#28601362)

   To invoke it during `load` event, consider putting it in `<h:outputScript target="body">`. The `target="body"` automatically puts the `<script>` in end of `<body>`, thus a `$(document).ready()` wrapper is unnecessary.

   ```
    <h:outputScript target="body">
        document.getElementById("form:button").onclick();
    </h:outputScript>
   ```

   ---
5. Or, create a custom `UIComponent` which extends `UICommand` and generates the necessary JSF native `jsf.ajax.request()` call. As an example you could look at [source code](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/component/script/CommandScript.java) of OmniFaces `<o:commandScript>`.

Comment: Thank's BalusC! 
The problem was solved with your secound option, using the component remoteCommand, now it's working 100%!