# JSF call click on button from javascript not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to click a button after the page loading to open a pop up window with some information:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function doHiddenClickPuntoAgua() {
            document.getElementById("form:puntoAgua").click();
        }
</script>

<p:commandButton id="puntoAgua"
        actionListener="#{viewGestionBean.openDialogAgua()}"
        style="display: none;">
        <p:ajax event="dialogReturn"
            listener="#{gestionBean.actualizaTabla()}"
            update=":form:tablaUbicaciones" />
    </p:commandButton>
```

I see that the function is calling from then backbean but the actionListener not working in my command button why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to invoke a JSF managed bean on a HTML DOM event using native JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588327/how-to-invoke-a-jsf-managed-bean-on-a-html-dom-event-using-native-javascript)

Comment: See https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml?jfwid=47455

Answer (score -1):

your DOM selector is not referencing the target correctly, try

```
function doHiddenClickPuntoAgua() {
    document.getElementById("puntoAgua").click();
}
doHiddenClickPuntoAgua()
```

Comment: There likely is a `h:form` which prepended it ID (as naming containers do in JSF)