# JSF how button action waits ajax change event complete

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, action

Hello I have one problem,
I have one input with one ajax change event. The change method checks if input has more than 100 entries and If is true it splitting the input. E.x I insert 200 entries into input, change method gives me two inputs in UI with 100 entries each. The problem is I have one search button with one action for search. I want this action execute after change event. So if I enter 200 entries and click search button I want  split to complete and after trigger button action method. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to invoke a JSF managed bean on a HTML DOM event using native JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588327/how-to-invoke-a-jsf-managed-bean-on-a-html-dom-event-using-native-javascript)

Comment: No did not. Looking something how synchronized onchange with click function. I want click function triggered when onchange finished