# JSF multiple actionListeners called in order with update

Tags: jsf, actionlistener

Using JSF 2 I understand I can call multiple actionListeners as such:

```
<h:commandButton value="Action">
    <f:actionListener binding="#{myBean.actionOne()}" />
    <f:actionListener binding="#{myBean.actionTwo()}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

However, I would like to call one actionListener and perform an `update` to the @form. Once this first call and update are complete call a 2nd actionListener and perform another `update`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. With [`<h:commandScript>`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/2.3/vdldoc/html_basic/commandscript).

```xml
<h:form>
    ...
    <h:commandButton value="Action" action="#{myBean.actionOne}">
        <f:ajax render="@form" onevent="function(data) {
            if (data.status === 'success') actionTwo();
        }"/>
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:commandScript name="actionTwo" action="#{myBean.actionTwo}"
         render="...">
    </h:commandScript>
</h:form>
```

In case you're not on JSF 2.3 yet, see [How to invoke a JSF managed bean on a HTML DOM event using native JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588327/how-to-invoke-a-jsf-managed-bean-on-a-html-dom-event-using-native-javascript/16588912#16588912) for alternatives.

In case you're using PrimeFaces (given away by your question history confirms this and using the term 'update' instead of 'render'), the [`<p:remoteCommand>`](http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml) is the equivalent.

```xml
<h:form>
    ...
    <p:commandButton value="Action" action="#{myBean.actionOne}"
         update="@form" oncomplete="actionTwo()">
    </p:commandButton>
    <p:remoteCommand name="actionTwo" action="#{myBean.actionTwo}"
         update="...">
    </p:remoteCommand>
</h:form>
```