# How do suppress my PrimeFaces ajaxStatus when using OmniFaces socket and JSF core commandScript?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

My application uses PrimeFaces' global p:ajaxStatus. Whenever I need to suppress/avoid this behaviour, I use global="false" on specific components such as p:commandButton and the like.

But in this particular case, I need to use use o:socket and h:commandScript like this:

```
<o:socket channel="controllerEventChannel" scope="view" onmessage="onMessage" />

<h:commandScript name="onMessage" actionListener="#{backingBean.callback()}" />
```

*I'm not sure if it's o:socket or h:commandScript that's actually triggering ajaxStatus.*

If I use p:remoteCommand, the message format breaks the callback method in which I use OmniFaces Faces.getRequestParameter(key). This locks me out from using global="false" on p:remoteCommand.

Any creative suggestions on how to manually suppress the ajax status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's unfortunately not possible. According to the [source code of the JS behind `<p:ajaxStatus>`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/13.0.3/primefaces/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/ajaxstatus/ajaxstatus.js#L118) they don't support skipping the standard Faces `ajax.addOnEvent()` listener based on a certain attribute on the source DOM element behind `data.source` or a predefined request parameter behind `data.options.params`.

Your best bet is therefore to use `<p:remoteCommand global="false">` and convert the request parameter map argument format acceptable by the JS function behind `<h:commandScript>` to the one for `<p:remoteCommand>` as follows:

```java
Map<String, Object> paramsForCommandScript = Map.of("name1", "value1", "name2", "value2");
List<Map<String, Object>> paramsForRemoteCommand = paramsForCommandScript.entrySet().stream()
    .map(param -> Map.of("name", param.getKey(), "value", param.getValue()))
    .toList();
controllerEventChannel.send(paramsForRemoteCommand);
```

#### See also:

- [How to invoke a JSF managed bean on a HTML DOM event using native JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588327/how-to-invoke-a-jsf-managed-bean-on-a-html-dom-event-using-native-javascript/)

Comment: That worked like a charm! My hero!